# Download Image from API Results

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, download

I am creating an app that uses an online API to render images based off a searched keyword. I run a forEach loop to render 12 images in the page in divs. Is there a way to download the pictures if I were to click a button even when I don't know what the results of search will be ahead of time because different users will type in different key words? I am using node.js express and javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>GIF</h1>
  <a href="/home">HOME</a>
  <form action="/home/gif" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="gif" placeholder="Search Gif By Keyword">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
  </form>
  <div class="gif">
    <h2>Seached Results</h2>
    <% gif.forEach((value) => { %>
      <img src="<%= value.images.original.url %>">
    <%})%>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "download them" mean in your context.  Download them to where?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a template library, but you didn't mention which one. Without knowing anything more about that, you could try using an anchor link with the `download` attribute. For example:

```
<div class="gif">
  <h2>Seached Results</h2>
  <% gif.forEach((value) => { %>
    <img src="<%= value.images.original.url %>">
    <a href="<%= value.images.original.url %>" download>Download</a>
  <%})%>
</div>
```

This way, when the user clicks the link, the browser will download whatever is at the href. (Which in this case should be the image.)

Note that `download` is an HTML5 attribute. You can check the browser compatibility for it here: http://caniuse.com/#search=download.